# ADF v1 to v2 Migration issue

Tags: azure-data-factory

Currently I am trying to migrate my data factory version from v1 to v2 by using tool "Azure Data Factory v1 to v2Migration Tool", I have downloaded and installed the tool from
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=57269

But when I run it I get the error.

> Unable to connect with to azure with the specified source credentials.
>   the user does not have access to specified subscriptionID
>   ressourceGroup, or dataFactory.

[image]

I made following changes in my linked service.
1)destination is created with linked services having working connection strings
2) Service name is also exactly same as ADF 1, but still facing the same issue having popup window..

any help will be appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: Reference this blog:https://azuredatafactoryv2.github.io/v1tov2migration/, maybe you could help you solve the error.

Comment: Thanks for reply, this blog is the initial point of start of my work, but connecting with the tool is not working anymore, still looking for the solution..